# Updating column in MSSQL quickly

Tags: c#, sql-server, amazon-ec2

I am using an Microsoft SQL Web server on Amazon RDS.  The system is currently generating timeouts when updating one column, I am trying to resolve the issue or at least minimize it.  Currently the updates occur when a device calls in and they call in a lot, to the point where a device may call back before the webserver finished the last call.

Microsoft SQL Server Web (64-bit)
Version 13.0.4422.0

I see a couple potential possibilities here.  First is the device is calling back before the system finished handling the last call so the same record is being updated multiple times concurrently.  The second possibility is that I am running into a row lock or table lock.

The table has about 3,000 records in total.

Note I am only trying to update one column in one row at a time.  The other columns are never updated.

I don't need to have the last updated time to be very accurate, would there be any benefit to changing the code to only update the column if say greater than a few minutes or would that just add more load to the server?  Any suggestion on how to optimize this?  Maybe move it to a function, store procedure, or something else?

Suggested new code:

```
UPDATE [Devices] SET [LastUpdated] = GETUTCDATE()
WHERE [Id] = @id AND 
([LastUpdated] IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(MI, [LastUpdated], GETUTCDATE()) > 2);
```

Existing update code:

```
internal static async Task UpdateDeviceTime(ApplicationDbContext db, int deviceId, DateTime dateTime)
{
    var parm1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@id", deviceId);
    var parm2 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@date", dateTime);
    var sql = "UPDATE [Devices] SET [LastUpdated] = @date WHERE [Id] = @Id";
    // timeout occurs here.
    var cnt = await db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(sql, new object[] { parm1, parm2 });
}
```

Table creation script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Devices](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CompanyId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Button_MAC_Address] [nvarchar](17) NOT NULL,
[Password] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[TimeOffset] [int] NOT NULL,
[CreationTime] [datetime] NULL,
[LastUpdated] [datetime] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Devices] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,   ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Devices] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Devices_CompanyId]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [CompanyId]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Devices] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Devices_TimeOffset]  DEFAULT ((-5)) FOR [TimeOffset]
GO  
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Devices] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Devices_CreationTime]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [CreationTime]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Devices] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_Devices] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: create index on LastUpdated column, and don't use DATEDIFF, use LastUpdated < DATEADD(day, -2, GETUTCDATE()). But tbh 3k rows is nothing, a full table scan is not expansive at all

Comment: 3000 rows is no data at all. It isn't enough to fill a single core's registers, much less its cache. If you have *timeouts* there is a different problem. You may be trying to modify rows locked by another transaction/connection. Did you check the Activity Monitor in SSMS? Does it show any blocked sessions?

Comment: And why are you using ApplicationDbContext which is used by Identity? Are you *sure* it hasn't opened any transactions?

Comment: I'm using the ApplicationDbContext because the rest of the site uses it, it is an MVC site so that is what is there.  I looked into changing but did not see any difference if I used the sp_executesql, no transitions if I don't create one.

Comment: As for profiling it, yes I have tried and normally the update duration fall into the zero range.  It just get in this mode where I start getting lots of timeouts, it seems when load increases.   That is why I am trying to shorten the update time when the system is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the cause by using a tool such as profiler or other techniques to detect blocking.  I dont see why you would have a problem updating one column your table with only 3,000 records.  It might have something to do with your constraints.

If it really is a timing issue, then you can consider in memory OLTP, designed to handle this type of scenario.

Last updated could also be stored in a transaction based table with a link back to this table with a join using Max(UpdatedTime).  In this case you would never update just add new records.

You can then either use partitioning or a cleanup routine to keep the size of this transaction table down.

> Programming patterns that In-Memory OLTP will improve include
>   concurrency scenarios, point lookups, workloads where there are many
>   inserts and updates, and business logic in stored procedures.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn133186(v=sql.120).aspx